# What should I name Borrowed and lent money section?

Tags: personal-loan

I'm developing an app for my personal finance management. My app has a section where it records the amount of money I have borrowed from friends or lent to them. I googled a lot to find a name for that section, so finally I founded the closest word LIABILITIES but I'm not sure if that is the correct name for it?

Your answer will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would like to suggest a feature for your app. After using the Money Lover app for a few years now, there is one feature that I wish it had. I think it would be nice to have the ability to make future projections on expenses, based on my expenses in the past x months. For instance, I should be able to predict an expense of $780 based expenses in the last 3 months. Or a projected spending of about $1,200 based on expenses in the last month. Consider such a feature if you find it useful as well.

Comment: @OkiemuteOmuta Thanks bro, sounds great and I'll definitely take it into consideration for my current app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Private Loans` both `Owe` and `Owed`.

In my personal finance spreadsheets, I like to separate `Loans` (money that I've already borrowed) from `Liabilities` (money that I'm going to owe some time in the foreseeable future, like annual taxes, semiannual insurance payments, etc), even though that isn't the textbook accurate definition of `Liabilities`.

Answer (score 2):

In formal bookkeeping, *liabilities* is [an obligation arising from a past business event](https://www.accountingcoach.com/blog/what-is-a-liability) and which has not yet been settled. Liabilities is the opposite of *assets*, which are [the resources of the company that have been acquired through transactions, and [which] have future economic value that can be measured and expressed in [some currency]](https://www.accountingcoach.com/balance-sheet/explanation).

An example of a liability is a personal loan, a mortgage, or an as of yet unpaid bill (which may or may not have been issued yet, but where the business transaction has occurred; an example of this would be a charge to a credit card where the bill has not yet been sent to the credit card holder). Compare also [commitments and contingent liabilities](https://www.accountingcoach.com/balance-sheet/explanation/2).

An example of an asset is the money in one's bank account, a vehicle (which can be sold for cash), or stock in a company.

Consequently, it wouldn't be *wrong* to use the terms ***liabilities* for money the user has borrowed from others, and *assets* for money the user has lent to others.** However, depending on your target audience, it might be rather on the technical side.

Comment: Thanks dude, but since I'm not familiar with accounting terms and terminologies still I couldn't understand clearly what to say. When I search online I find answers same as yours. Complicated answer, sorry to say this.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through a couple of financial planning apps, I finally settled with Money Lover.

When making an entry in the Money Lover app, all of these are placed under the **Debt & Loan** category. That broad category then has Debt, Debt Collection, Loan and (loan) Repayment.

Now if you want to view monies that you owe or that are owed to you, there is a **Debts menu** for all these. Under that menu, you have two tabs: Payable (monies you owe) and Receivable (monies owed to you).

I hope this helps too.